# terraform cloudflare loop for records

Tags: terraform, cloudflare

I have a setup of terraform cloudflare push with below configuration:

```
locals {
    ResourceRecordSets= [
        {
            Name =  "example.com.",
            Type =  "A",
            TTL =  60,
            ResourceRecords =  [
                {
                    Value =  "1.2.3.4"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Using this `locals` value I am pushing DNS records as:

```
resource "cloudflare_record" "com_records" {
  count = length(local.ResourceRecordSets)

  zone_id = cloudflare_zone.site.id
  name    = local.ResourceRecordSets[count.index].Name
  value   = local.ResourceRecordSets[count.index].ResourceRecords.value
  type    = local.ResourceRecordSets[count.index].Type
  proxied = false
  ttl     = 1
}
```

The only thing I am struggling with is the `value` section. sometime it can be a `MX` records with multiple values under  `ResourceRecords`. What type of loop should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **flatten** your ResourceRecordSets, for example:

```
  FlatResourceRecordSets = merge([
    for idx, ResourceRecordSet in local.ResourceRecordSets:
      {
        for ResourceRecord in ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords:
            "${idx}-${ResourceRecord.Value}" => {
              ResourceRecordSet = ResourceRecordSet
              ResourceRecord =  ResourceRecord["Value"]
          }
      }
    ]...) # please do NOT remove the dots
```

then

```
resource "cloudflare_record" "com_records" {
  for_each = local.FlatResourceRecordSets

  zone_id = cloudflare_zone.site.id
  name    = each.value["ResourceRecordSet"].Name
  value   = each.value["ResourceRecord"]
  type    = each.value["ResourceRecordSet"].Type
  proxied = false
  ttl     = 1
}
```

Comment: This works. The only problem I am still facing is for MX records. Something like:

            TTL =  3600,
            MXRecords =  [
                {
                    "Value" =  "1 aspmx.l.google.com"
                },
                {
                    "Value" =  "5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com"
                },
                {
                    "Value" =  "5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com"
                },

Comment: @Ajayk Glad it work. For MX issue, I would suggest a new question.

Comment: There is a problem with the data blocks vs values here, i don't see an easy solution to solve that within one resource.